# Putting jQuery popup window in the center of page always?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got this code that allows a nice pop up window when clicked on a particular image. This brings out a larger image for a gallery I made. However for some reason I can't get it to appear at the center of the user's window, as all the images are different sizes, they move depending on the image shown.

The link is at:

http://zeendesign.co.uk/cherrieimogen/cherrieimogen/cherrieImogen/portfolio.html

(the css is called reveal.css)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the script?

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that left on the container must be set to 20% and that's what the script's doing.

Try setting left based on (windowWidth-containerwidth)/2.

i.e.:

```
v = Math.floor(($(window).width()-$("#myModal").outerWidth())/2)+"px";
$("#myModal").css("left",v);
```

Answer (score 0):

Position the dialog after the image is loaded.

```
$('#dlg') 
.dialog('open')            
.dialog({position:'center'});
```